# What is a convention for naming a constant in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, constants, naming-conventions

In shell scripting, even though I use `Java` or `Python` style naming convention, I am still unclear about naming a constant.

Many conventions suggest me to use "capital letter" together with "underscore" for naming a constant e.g. `MY_CONSTANT`, `PI`. But in `Bash`, this may conflict with [environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).

So, what is the right naming convention for Bash constants?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Together with the question you are linking, there is another related question in Unix & Linux: [Are there naming conventions for variables in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42847/40596).

There you can find a couple of good answers:

> Variables that are introduced by the operating system or start up
> scripts etc. are usually all in `CAPITALS`, these are called
> '*envrironment* variables'.
>
> To prevent your own variables from conflicting with environment
> variables, it is a good practice to use `lower case`.

Together with a [Shell Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml#Naming_Conventions) link, where you can find:

> #### Naming Conventions
>
> Function Names
>
> ▶ Lower-case, with underscores to separate words. Separate libraries
> with ::. Parentheses are required after the function name. The keyword
> function is optional, but must be used consistently throughout a
> project.
>
> Variable Names
>
> ▶ As for function names.
>
> Constants and Environment Variable Names
>
> ▶ All caps, separated with underscores, declared at the top of the
> file.

There is no suggested convention in `man bash`, just note the "be careful with uppercase" warning.